# Finding an index in range of values between 0-100 in Python

Tags: python, list, syntax, range

This is a two part question, I have to make a selection of 2 indexes via a random range of any number of integers in a list. Can't return both if they're both in the same range as well

```
Selection1 = random.randint(0,100)
Selection2 = random.randint(0,100)
```

For the sake of this argument, say:

```
Selection1 = 10
Selection2 = 17
And the list would be like so [25, 50, 75, 100]
```

Both would return the index of 0 because they fall between 0-25

So both would fall into the first index range, the problem is i'm having some issues trying to fit it into this range (IE: 0-25) which will return this first index (return list[0])

What is the syntax for this type of logic in python?

I'm sure I can figure out how to return different indexes if they fall in the same range, probably just loop reset to the loop but if I can get some advice on that it wouldn't hurt.

I'll give the code i'm working with right now as a guideline. Mostly at the bottom is where i'm struggling.

Code Here

```
def roulette_selection(decimal_list, chromosome_fitness, population):
    percentages = []
    for i in range(population):
        result = decimal_list[i]/chromosome_fitness
        result = result * 100
        percentages.append(result)

    print(percentages)
    range_in_fitness = []
    current_percent = 0

    for i in range(population):
        current_percent = percentages[i] + current_percent
        range_in_fitness.append(current_percent)
    parent1 = random.randint(0, 100)
    parent2 = random.randint(0, 100)

    for i in range(population):
        if parent1 >= range_in_fitness[i] and parent1<=range_in_fitness[i+1]:


    print(parent1, parent2)
    print(range_in_fitness)
```

Comment: Could you fix the indentation of your code? You've got the function def inline with everything else, and the last two print statements should be under the if?

Comment: @MasterOdin Ok sorry about that, it should be fixed now, no, the range of fitness is fixed and so are the parents, no need to put them in the if statement, but that is where the code is supposed be, i'm just not where to go from the if statement, and it doesn't even work, I just wanted to point people in the right direction and where i'm trying to go with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your list of ranges is sorted, or it is acceptable to sort it, and is contiguous (no gaps), you can use Python's [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) module to do this in an efficient manner. Example:

```
>>> l = [25, 50, 75, 100]
>>> import bisect
>>> bisect.bisect(l, 10)
0
>>> bisect.bisect(l, 17)
0
>>> bisect.bisect(l, 55)
2
>>> bisect.bisect(l, 25)
1
```

Bisect returns the index of where the input number should fall into the list to maintain sort order. Note that this is a little confusing to think about at first; In the case of `55` above, it returns `2` because it should be inserted at index 2 as it falls between the current values at indices `1` and `2`. If you give it a number exactly on a range boundary, it will 'fall to the right', as evidenced by the `bisect(l,25)` example.

The linked documentation includes a set of recipes for searching through sorted lists using `bisect`.

Answer (score 1):

Given an input `val` and a list of range delimiters `delims`, here are two approaches:

```
# Both methods require range_delims to be sorted
range_delims = [25,50,75,100]

# Simple way
def find_range1(val, delims):
    for i,d in enumerate(delims):
        if val < d: return i

print find_range1(10,  range_delims)  # 0
print find_range1(17,  range_delims)  # 0
print find_range1(32,  range_delims)  # 1
print find_range1(64,  range_delims)  # 2
print find_range1(96,  range_delims)  # 3
print find_range1(101, range_delims)  # None


# More explicit, possibly unnecessarily so
import math

def find_range2(val, delims):
    lbl = [float('-inf')] + delims
    ubl = delims + [float('inf')]
    for (i,(lb,ub)) in enumerate(zip(lbl, ubl)):
        if lb <= val < ub: return i

print find_range2(10,  range_delims)  # 0
print find_range2(17,  range_delims)  # 0
print find_range2(32,  range_delims)  # 1
print find_range2(64,  range_delims)  # 2
print find_range2(96,  range_delims)  # 3
print find_range2(101, range_delims)  # 4
```

The first just compares `val` to the elements of `delims` and when it finds that `val` is less than the element, returns the index of that element.

The second is a little more verbose, generating both upper and lower bounds, and ensuring that `val` is between them.  For interior elements of `delims` the bounds are list elements, for the 2 exterior elements of `delims`, the bounds are the element and either + or - infinity.

Note: Both approaches require the input list of delimiters to be sorted.  There are ways to deal with different delimiter list formats, but it looks like you have a sorted list of delimiters (or could sort it without issue).

Comment: both are highly unefficient. answer from aruisdante is much faster (and deals with the upper bound)