# Python-search function

Tags: python

I want to write a search function that takes in a value x and a sorted sequence and returns the position that the value should go to by iterating through the elements of the sequence starting from the first element. The position that x should go to in the list should be the first position such that it will be less than or equal to the next element in the list.

```
 Example:>>> search(-5, (1, 5, 10))——0
         >>> search(3, (1, 5, 10))——1
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Just answered a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29088837/finding-an-index-in-range-of-values-between-0-100-in-python/29089021#29089021)

Comment: that function already exists in python.

Comment: also, why would you want to iterate all the elements? you list is sorted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building a list of every item would be a bit of a waste of resources if there were big gaps in the list, instead you can just iterate through each list item until the input is bigger than the value.

In terms of your code -

```
def search(input,inputList):
    for i in range( len( inputList ) ):
        if inputList[i]>input:
            return i
    return len( inputList )

print search(-5, (1, 5, 10))
#Result: 0
print search(3, (1, 5, 10))
#Result: 1
```

To insert it into the list, this would work, I split the list in 2 based on the index and add the value in the middle.

```
def insert(input,inputList):
    index = search(input,inputList)                    #Get where the value should be inserted
    newInput = [input]+list(inputList[index:])         #Add the end of the list to the input
    if index:
        newInput = list(inputList[:index])+newInput    #Add the start of the list if the index isn't 0
    return newInput

print insert(-5, (1, 5, 10))
#Result: (-5, 1, 5, 10)
print insert(3, (1, 5, 10))
#Result: (1, 3, 5, 10)
```

Comment: If I want to insert the input into the exact position of the list, what should I do? Take 'search(3,(1,5,10))' as an example: how can I put 3 in position 1?

Comment: What happens when the input value is greater than the highest value in the list?

Comment: Added a bit on how to insert the values, and thanks for pointing it out haha, I didn't actually try it with larger numbers but it's fixed now :)

Comment: Note that iterating through a sorted list in this manner is not efficient. If the list is already sorted, you should use a binary search to accomplish your task.

Comment: How to write a binary search function instead of the original one?

Comment: I could probably throw one together but it wouldn't be very efficient, if you want it to run as fast as possible you're better off googling 'python binary search' :)

Answer (score 1):

since someone has answered a similar question, I will just draw a rough skeleton of what u may want to do.

declare a list and populate it with your stuff;
    mylist = [1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 6, 7]

then just make a function and iterate the list;

```
def my_func( x, mylist):
    for i in mylist:
        if((mylist[i] == x)|| (mylist[i] > x)):
            return i
```

Given 3 in list (1, 2, 3, 4, 5), the function should return index 2. 
Given 3 in list (1, 2, 4, 5, 6), it should still return 2

You may want to check my python code, because I have not checked this for errors, I am assuming you know some python and if you have the skeleton, you should crack it. And Oh, python cares about the tabbibg I did.

Comment: You could simplify that if condition to `xlist[i] >= x`